# Question about integral of an odd function

Tags: calculus

I am studying something and encountered this:
"
Let $R(\theta,T) = \int_{-T}^{T} \frac{(\sin \theta t)}{t}dt, S(T) = \int_0^T\frac{(\sin x)}{x}dx$, then for $\theta > 0$ and changing variables $t=x/\theta $ shows that

$R(\theta,T)=2\int_0^{T\theta}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx = 2S(T\theta)$ while for $\theta<0$, $R(\theta,T) = -R(|\theta|,T)$" which I don't understand.

If $\theta<0$, then $R(\theta,T)=2\int_{-T|\theta|}^{0}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx =2\int_0^{T|\theta|}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx = R(|\theta|,T)$ as $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is an even function, right? I am missing something simple here, thanks and appreciate an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $t=-T$ we get $x=t\theta =-T\theta =T|\theta|$ and not $-T|\theta|$.

Comment: Correct! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}\theta <0 & \Rightarrow  R(\theta ,T)=\int_{-T}^T\frac{\sin (\theta t)}{t}dt\\
&\Rightarrow R(\theta ,T)=\int_{-T}^T\frac{\sin (-|\theta| t)}{t}dt\\
&\Rightarrow R(\theta ,T)=-\int_{-T}^T\frac{\sin (|\theta| t)}{t}dt \ \ \ [\because \sin(-x)=-\sin (x)\big]\\
&\Rightarrow R(\theta ,T)=-R(|\theta|,T)\\
\end{align}$$